# three.js r73 shader material attributes

Tags: three.js

I get an error:

> THREE.ShaderMaterial: attributes should now be defined in THREE.BufferGeometry
>   THREE.ShaderMaterial: 'attributes' is not a property of this material.

and i'm trying to figure out what is going on.

I used to make a buffer geometry with some attributes. I never really figured out why this was needed, but i did notice i need to "type" it of sorts, to get three to hook it up with the shader.

```
{
    attributes: {
        aSomeAttribute:{
            type: 'v3', 
            value:null
        }
    }
}
```

i'm trying to figure out what material.prototype.setValues( parameter ) does. From what i see it takes the parameters passed to the material ({vertexShader:...,uniforms:...}) and goes bonkers when it encounters attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now apply custom attributes only on geometries inheriting from THREE.BufferGeometry for example if it's a sphere use THREE.SphereBufferGeometry instead of THREE.SphereGeometry. Then create your array of attributes and add it to the geometry thanks to THREE.BufferGeometry. After that you will be able to use your attribute in your shader. You can find an example [here](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_custom_attributes.html).

Comment: there was some cruft left in the source code where these attributes were still being cloned with a shader material, hence it was a bit confusing. I pretty much don't change anything, except removing the attributes:{} from the shadermaterial constructor. Why it was needed in the first place, i never figured it out, the value i put there was always null.

Comment: Quick somwhat related question. In the example they still use loadTexture instead of the new textureLoader. Do you know how to use the new textureLoader while creating a shaderMaterial?